# Google Maps API crashes older iOS mobile Safari

Tags: wordpress, google-maps-api-3

I am calling a map via google maps v3 api on my personal website. Everything seems to be working fine - until I was told my website makes mobile devices crash...

After the initial shock and horror I started testing multiple devices but it only seems to affect older iOS versions. It's running fine on iPhone 4 & 5 with latest iOS 6. It crashes my iPAD 1 on iOS 5.1 and have seen it also crash iPhone 4S (unknown iOS); Android phones I have tested with seemed to work fine ... So if my observations are correct it seems to be a version rather than performance issue.

The only other reference on a problem like this I found here: http://blog.rotacoo.com/lazy-loading-instances-of-the-google-maps-api ... although there the problem seems to be a multitude of API calls. I only execute one...

So far I tried calling v3.8 / v3.9 / 3.10 of Google Maps API, reset the map I load to the basic settings etc, asynch loading...  but the problem seems to be consistent...

Currently I am loading API in the header like this:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=****&sensor=false"></script>
```

I did try to load it via enqueue script in the functions.php, but it seems the & create a lot of problems...

I am running latest Wordpress and you can see the site at: [www.deborre.net](http://www.deborre.net)

Would very much appreciate any help! Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My best guess is that this is a total amount of memory issue on these devices. iPhones running iOS < 4 are almost all very old devices. It's unfortunate though that this affects the original iPad on iOS 5.

WordPress sites tend to not be optimized well. Simply look at the sheer number of <script> tags and stylesheets on your page.

While this isn't the best of answers, try to reduce the number external scripts and stylesheets on your page and see if that makes a difference. Having built WordPress themes, this of course is not particularly easy to do.

Comment: Thanks for the answere. I had disabled all plugins and took out all the functionality leaving only the very basic map .. and still as soon as google maps api starts loading it crashes. What confuses me the most is that it doesn't seem to be device performance (it crashed an iPhone 4S but didn't bother an iPhone 4) but the iOS version that's signigicant.

Will try and strip down all extra features again and isolate the problem like that...

I was just hoping someone would spot an error in me loading Google API - or even had experienced something similar before.

Comment: I haven't seen this exact issue no. You might try making a static page (non-wordpress) with the same map logic and see if this also crashes. That would be easier for people to look through. I scanned your code and didn't see any obvious errors.

Comment: Hey thanks again, I did follow your advise and firstly copied the entire page generated by WP into a new static page.. with the same crash result ... then again took out script by script always crashing until Maps API was removed ... BUT THEN I simply took out content and reduced page load and that seems to do the trick ... Still baffled it has such great effect though. But at least this gives me a starting point for opimisation now... Thanks again!

Comment: Older mobile safari has some pretty restrictive memory limitations. These aren't related directly to the device specifications.

Comment: the strange thing is, it does happen when using chrome on iOS too. or is that bound to the same limitions anyway?

Comment: To my knowledge, any web browser on iOS uses the same WebKit rendering engine. It's a restriction by Apple.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is late, but I was having the same problem and I got rid of the marker animation.  I was trying to use a custom marker with the DROP animation, which works well on desktop but consistently crashed my iPad 2.  Not sure if this is the solution to the problem stated here, but it might save someone some headbanging in the future.

Also, I am using Modernizr, so my final code looks like this (tested on iPad2 and iPhone5 - both iOS6):

```
new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng($this.attr('data-lat'), $this.attr('data-lon')),
    map: map,
    animation: Modernizr.touch ? '' : google.maps.Animation.DROP,
    icon: icon,
    shadow: shadow
});
```